# jQuery .load() with get parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Need to send AJAX data with get parameters from php variable

```
<?php
  $startdate="2017-11-23 14:32:00";
?>

<script>  
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#load").load("loader.php", {startdate:<?php echo $startdate;?>});
  }, 10000); 
</script>
```

loader.php

```
<?php
  $startdate=$_POST['startdate'];
?>
<script>
  $("#load").empty();   
  $("#load").html('<?php echo $startdate;?>');  
</script>
```

But nothing returns to block "load". Where is my fault? Thanks!

Comment: `.load()` Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. does not send. you might wanna try `.post()` or `.get()`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that does not seem to be the problem. .load sends to the server just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want something like this.

Note the quotes in the JSON string and also look in the console (F12)
I added jQuery too. You need to load that to run the script you have

*index.php*

```
<?php
$startdate="2017-11-23 14:32:00";
?>
<div id="load"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>  
setInterval(function() {
  $("#load").load("loader.php", {"startdate":"<?php echo $startdate;?>"});
}, 10000); 
</script>
```

*loader.php* - html is an example

```
<?PHP 
  $startdate=$_POST['startdate']; 
  // do something with it
  echo "I <b>received</b> and <i>processed</i> ".$startdate; 
?>
```